# Creating a variable that counts the number of another variable satisfying a condition in R

Tags: r, sequence

| id | date | score | Repeat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1991 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 1992 | 1.5 | 3 |
| 1 | 1993 | -1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1989 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1990 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1991 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1992 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1993 | -3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1994 | -2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1995 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1996 | 4 | 2 |

Like the above table, I have ID, date and two other variables, score and repeat. If score is greater than 0 for consecutive dates for the same person, it adds 1 to repeat. If not it suddenly becomes 0. I want to write a code to make this work for repeat variable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What if the score hits below zero then is above zero on the next turn?

Comment: @AllanCameron see the second/third case for id 3. In that case it just starts again with 1. But also for id 2 it seems that whenever the counter is "reset" to 0, the next case starts with 1 (and not with the max number of whatever has been assigned to in an earlier case).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using hutilscpp. Let me know if this works:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(hutilscpp)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(repeats = hutilscpp::cumsum_reset(score > 0))
```